# SignalR and Autofac: Most up to date method of integrating

Tags: dependency-injection, signalr, autofac

There is documentation for using Autofac with SignalR here:

https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/SignalRIntegration

But this appears to be quite old. The 2.0 release of SignalR seems to have improved the story for DI. The following appears to be instructions for SignalR 2.0 DI:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/extensibility/dependency-injection

Which is the preferred method and can anyone give some pointers on implementing the second approach with Autofac? Sorry I'm relatively new to both signalR and Autofac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice way to use your own dependency resolver:

```
// This is all done in the initial startup
var myDependencyResolver = ....;

app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
{
    Resolver = myDependencyResolver
});

// If you want to use GlobalHost you need to update its resolver.
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = myDependencyResolver;
```

That's all you should need to do.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is where I start to get confused. I have an existing web api project where all the IoC setup is done in global.asax Application_Start. But the app.MapSignalR call above is in an OWIN startup class.  How can I share my IoC container between the two? Should setting the GlobalHost.DependencyResolver in global.asax suffice without setting the HobConfiguration.Resolver in the OwinStartup class?

Comment: With SignalR 2.0.0 you must have an Owin Startup class (you no longer use the Application_Start method).  Therefore I'd recommend you do all your configuration within the owin configuration (instead of app start).

Comment: Thanks, accepted as answer as this does work - I was seeing an unrelated issue because I was calling the Autofac RegisterHubs method incorrectly!  Any pointers for moving my webapi configuration from Application_Start to Owin?  Or should it pretty much just be cut\paste?